# Deploying to appengine hangs

Tags: google-app-engine

I just tried to deploy my app 5 times, and every times it hangs forever:

```
08:02 PM Starting deployment.
08:02 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:02 PM Will check again in 1 seconds.
08:02 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:02 PM Will check again in 2 seconds.
08:02 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:02 PM Will check again in 4 seconds.
08:02 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:02 PM Will check again in 8 seconds.
08:02 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:02 PM Will check again in 16 seconds.
08:02 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:02 PM Will check again in 32 seconds.
08:03 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:03 PM Will check again in 60 seconds.
08:04 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:04 PM Will check again in 60 seconds.
08:05 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:05 PM Will check again in 60 seconds.
08:06 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:06 PM Will check again in 60 seconds.
08:07 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:07 PM Will check again in 60 seconds.
08:08 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:08 PM Will check again in 60 seconds.
08:07 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:07 PM Will check again in 60 seconds.
08:08 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:08 PM Will check again in 60 seconds.
08:07 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:07 PM Will check again in 60 seconds.
08:08 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
08:08 PM Will check again in 60 seconds.
```

I already tried this on two different apps and all of them go into this infinite loop and never actually deploy.

Answer (score 9):

This is a recurrent issue with GAE.  Something in the queue as other apps are deploying as well.  As frustrating as it is, just keep trying.  Nothing to be done on your end.

Comment: Wow, that's insane. Presumably it's better to let it "check again" than to quit and retry if it's a queueing issue?